# How do I get my React app to read/parse contents of an email attachment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, email-parsing

I'm writing a React app for my company that displays server status for technicians to review daily. I cannot seem to find an appropriate node module that can access an email account and parse the through text of a (.txt) file attachment on new emails so I can display the data in a component. I can find plenty of help for sending emails but not parsing through received, let alone one with an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the email account using IMAP. Because you will fetch all emails to your Email Account(like Company email) in the Node application.

I have mentioned the package that you can use to get all emails in your application.

https://npm.io/package/imap

After getting all emails then you can do anything because you have all the data.

> If you face any issues please comment, I will try my best to solve your issue.